# How to tell 'PowerShell' Copy-Item to unconditionally copy files

Tags: powershell

The following PowerShell script works if the resources are not there.

```
  Copy-Item $src_dir $dst_dir$agent_folder -recurse
```

But if the resources are there, it will say:

```
+   Copy-Item <<<<  $src_dir $dst_dir$agent_folder -recurse
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\Users\Pac\Desktop\Agents\Agent0\lib:S
   tring) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemComm
   and
```

What do I have to add to the command so that it will unconditionally copy the files?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

It has a `-force` parameter.​​​​

Answer (score 19):

From the documentation (`help copy-item -full`):

```
-force <SwitchParameter>
    Allows cmdlet to override restrictions such as renaming existing files as long as security is not compromised.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: I guess false means param not mandatory and False means the default value is $false